# Convert Array value as object property dynamically

Tags: powershell

I have list of users and i am trying to see if they belong to specific Azure AD group. At the end i want the result to be something like this.

```
EmailAddress     Group1  Group2
User1@email.com   Y         N
User2@email.com   N         Y
User3@email.com   Y         Y
```

Here is what i got so far:

```
#authenticate
Connect-MsolService

$users = "User1@email.com", "User2@email.com", "User3@email.com"
$groupLists = "Group1", "Group2"

#create the object with Email, and group name as property name
$output = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value ""

$groupLists | ForEach-Object{
    $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value ""

}

#go through each group and user and update the output array
$userExistsInGroup;

foreach ($groupName in $groupLists) {
    #get group info
    $group = Get-Msolgroup -All | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $groupName}
    
    #get all members of the group
    $members = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress    
    
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        If ($members -contains $user) {        
            $userExistsInGroup; = "Y"
        } Else {         
            $userExistsInGroup = "N"
        }

        # update Email and group property in $output object
         ......
    }
}
```

Need help updating $output object so that i can display the result the way i want it on the top?
since the same user might show up in different group during loop, if there is existing user in the object, then it will need to update property of the same user that matches with the group so that at the end each row output belongs to one user similar to what i have on the top.

Comment: And what is your question? Can you summarize what's the problem with your code?

Comment: @marsze basically need help to update $output so that i can display the result similar to what i have on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accommodate a dynamic list of groups, you can use this approach.

```
$userlist = "User1@email.com", "User2@email.com", "User3@email.com"

$grouplist = "Managers","Directors","Information Technology"

$grouphash = @{}

foreach($group in $grouplist)
{
    $grouphash[$group] = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId (Get-Msolgroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $group}).objectid
}

foreach($user in $userlist)
{
    $userhash = [ordered]@{
        EmailAddress = $user
    }
    $grouplist | ForEach-Object {
        $userhash.add($_,($user -in $grouphash[$_].emailaddress))
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$userhash
}
```

Each group name will be the property for that group containing true/false if the user is a member.

To collect all the output in a variable simply put `$variable =`  in front of the user foreach loop.

Here is what the output looks like in this example
[image]

Comment: i might be missing something, but wouldn't it do same number of calls.
in your code, in order to get group members, you are going through each of those group , getting their groupId and getting the members. Then for each user, you are checking if the member exists in the group or not. I like that code is much cleaner and concise though. One issue i see with this is if i ever add new AD group, i then have to define new groupmember variable and also add new property for that in the customobject.